# How to render .astro files in django

Tags: javascript, django, performance, astrojs

I tried to create a Django web app since the web pages had heavy js files so it took a long time to load the page. To tackle this problem I tried to implement Astro to create a static webpage.
But the problem here is that Django renders .astro files also as HTML.[image: Like shown in this image]

How do I tell Django to render .astro as an Astro file

Comment: If I read [their docs](https://docs.astro.build/guides/deploy) correctly, you have to build a JS application and then deploy it.

Answer (score 2):

Astro is a static site generator built on top of node.js. To have your static site served from your django application you would first need to build astro out, using:
`npm run build` or `yarn build` to have your site output in the `./dist` directory. From here you can then point your django server to serve those files.

Since Astro files are static they can be deployed in a number of different ways, you can read more about this [here](https://docs.astro.build/guides/deploy)

Hope that helped buddy, if you got any more questions you could always come and ask them in the [discord channel](https://astro.build/chat)